# Can my spouse/friend purchase a cashier's check for me?

Tags: united-states, banking, cashier-check

I roughly understand that cashieir's checks lifts the money from your account at the time of issue and can be cashed by the named recipient.

Can I use a Cashier's check issued to my spouse/friend ? (Same named recipient)

Situation:
I need to submit a cashier's check to an institution who accepts cashier's checks from a few big banks. Unluckily, I don't have an accoount with any of those banks but my spouse does.

Can I use the cashier's check that was issued to my spouse ?
Is that an accepted use of cashier's check ?

Comment: Its been too long since I bought one, but I'm trying to remember if cashier's checks even have the purchaser's name on them. From looking at online examples some have a "remitter" field, but your individual bank would decide if they have that field and if it is optional or can be whatever the purchaser requests (such as an account number or your name). If there is no field, or you choose what goes in it at purchase time, then the receiver would have no way of knowing you didn't buy it personally and is otherwise perfectly acceptable as well. Otherwise you'd need to check with the recipient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few sub-questions here:

1. **Is it legal.** Yes, absolutely. Your wife can certainly pay your bills and your debts.
2. **Will the bank issue the check and honour it?** Yes again. They don't care what the check is used for, or if it's your wife's bill or yours or somebody else's.
3. **Will the recipient accept it?** Probably, because in general they don't care who actually pays the bill, and having a spouse pay a bill is pretty common. But a check from someone else increases the possibility of fraud, so it would be wise to check with the recipient before doing this.

Comment: Verifiied, it works. They don't care who bought the cashier's check.